# How to handle multiple calls of the same get function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Using Ajax call i'm calling the below get function every 10 seconds so that i can monitor the status of some urls.

```
app.get('/getUrl', function(req, res) {
            var response = {};
            var keyArr = [];
            var urlData = [];
            var responses = [];
            var dataArr = [];
            var keyArrLength;


            //Listing All the URLS

            db.list(function(err, data) {
                keyArrLength = data.rows.length;
                dataArr = data.rows;
                console.log("keyArrLength" + keyArrLength);
                pushHost();
            });

            //Getting the key ie HOSTNAMES

            function pushHost() {
                dataArr.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
                    var host = arrayItem.key;
                    keyArr.push(host);
                    console.log("Array of hosts" + keyArr);

                });

                next(0); //Calling the main function
            }

            var urlResults = [];
            var allResponses = [];

            // Getting the Hostname and URL

            function next(index) {
                if (index === keyArrLength) { // No items left
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(allResponses));
                    return;
                } else { //Getting one URL at a time
                    db.get(keyArr[index], function(err, data) {
                        currentUrl = data.url;
                        hostname = data._id;
                        var options = {
                            url: "https://" + currentUrl,
                            strictSSL: false,
                            method: 'GET'
                        };

                        //Requesting data for that one URL

                        request(options, function(error, response, body) {

                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                var response = {};
                                response.body = JSON.parse(body);
                                response.hostname = hostname;
                                allResponses.push(response); //Pushing the data to final result

                            } else if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {

                                var response = {};

                                //Appending error results when it enters error handler

                                response.body = {
                                    "servicesStatus": [{
                                        "name": "name1",
                                        "active": false
                                    }, {
                                        "name": "name2",
                                        "active": false
                                    }, {
                                        "name": "name3",
                                        "active": false
                                    }],
                                }
                                response.hostname = hostname;
                                allResponses.push(response); //pushing data
                            }

                            next(index + 1); //Calling recursively till the last URL
                        });

                    });

                };

            }

        });
```

1)In `db.list i'm getting the list of all the URL's` and getting the length of or count of all the URLs.

2)In push host function i'm pushing all the keyvalues which is the hostname for that URL. So,In `keyArrLength has the total number of URLS and keyArr has the list of all the hostnames i.e keys`.

3)Then i'm calling the `next()`

4)In next() i'm making the request call for each url and store the data as a `form of object in an array allResponses[]`.

5)If it enters error handler, i'm appending the results to `allResponses[]`

6)I'm calling till the last url by assigning

```
 index=0 in the beginning and incrementing in each loop
```

7)IT works fine when i'm calling this function every 10 seconds.

8)But when i refresh the page , this `getUrl` will get called, and it will be already executing since this call is being made every 10seconds. So they both collide and the resullts are repeating.

I'm new to nodejs. I dont know whether i'm doing properly or is there any better way available to make these calls.

I want to know even if i refresh the page any number of times, i want this function to execute in order. If the latest call interupts the previous call , i need to terminate the previous call and start with the latest one.

Thanks a lot for reading this! Please do help if possible! suggest if you know any better ways to do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i found the issue.The above code is fine only. The problem was I didn't add `var` to this `hostname = data._id;`and hence it stored the previous value. That was the issue.